# tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout during request

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, http-error

I'm trying to make a long async http request using Python Tornado `AsyncHTTPClient`:

```
url = 'http://do_something_for_more_than_20_seconds.com/
client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
response = await client.fetch(url, method='GET')
```

But, after 20 seconds, I get this error:

```
tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout during request
```

How can I configure the `client` in order to allow long requests?

I have tried to add this configuration row after the initialization of the `client`, but still it doesn't work:

```
client.configure(None, defaults=dict(connect_timeout=60, request_timeout=120))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you move the configuration of timeouts in constructor of client

```
client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(defaults=dict(request_timeout=180))
```